# Convert a remote / dynamic sound file url (.mp3) to byte[] array format

Tags: android, arrays, mp3, waveform

I have a system, where it returns a sound file url (let's say .mp3 format). I want to get the byte[] of that mp3 file and create a custom waveform based on the same.

The function which I wrote, data should be fed to the function as byte[] format.

Comment: Do you use Kotlin or Java? Also, which library do you use to make requests to server?

Comment: @Natig Babayev I use Java and Retrofit